# I am looking for an npm package suggestion for scraping websites?

Tags: web-development, node.js, internet

If there is a better stack exchange site to ask this question please let me know.

But I need to use Node.js and some package to download web sites.

There is a slew of them:

There is the native Node request method - [http.request](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#http.request) and there is a native Node get method - [http.get](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/all.html#http.get).

There is a litany of other npm modules

- [website-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper)
- [request](https://github.com/request/request)
- more ...

There is also a tutorial by [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) and a similar ( not a duplicate ) older question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801453/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-download-a-page-and-gets-its-html)

Answer (score 1):

When the web-scrapping comes to my mind I remembers python based beautiful-soup or selenium  as tools I used to use before but if you want to work in NodeJS JavaScript I recommend you to checkout this post [The Ultimate Guide to Web Scraping with Node.js](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/) from freecodecamp on medium.